# What's the simplest way to control a 12V battery power supply using a Pi Zero?

Tags: power, pi-zero-w, home-automation

I'm short one garage door opener.  The simple option would be to buy a new one, but where's the fun in that when you can massively overengineer a solution using AWS IOT? I'm intending to hook one opener up to a Raspberry Pi Zero W inside the garage, then control it remotely from an android app.  I'm a software guy, all the comms & control is relatively easy, the bit I'm struggling with is to get the opener to send the signal in the first place.

The opener is an SOH4BMA 433MHz similar to the following pic, but in my case I think it's a 433.92MHz chip, not 330MHz.

[image]

If you press the red button, the LED lights up and the RF send the signal to the door.

I thought the simplest way to achieve this would be just to control the opener that I already have, rather than trying to rebuild the functionality from scratch.  So I've bypassed the red button so that the opener continually sends a signal when power is attached, then removed the battery and soldered cables to the power terminals.  My intention was to connect the positive terminal to a GPIO pin on a raspberry pi zero (and negative to GND), so that whenever the RPi sends a HIGH to the pin it completes the circuit and triggers the SOH4BMA to send the appropriate pulse

However the opener is set up for a 12V 23A battery, so when I put 3.3V or 5V across it from the RPi, nothing happens.

What's the simplest way to use the RPi to control this board?

I think one approach would be to reconnect the 12V battery and put a [relay](https://sg.cytron.io/p-2-channel-dc-5v-relay-module) in line, then use the RPi to control the relay.  Would that work?  It does however seem rather inelegant to have one power supply for the RPi and another one entirely for the opener.

It also seems to me that 12V is a lot more voltage than is really needed to drive this little thing, is there a better way to configure this?

Apologies: I'm a software guy trying to learn electronics, my knowledge of circuitry is.... well, 'developing' is probably the polite word

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The Pi is pretty irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It's quite possible you'll need to reprogram the remote every time you remove the battery. The right way would be to leave the battery in and simulate the button press.  It might be "inelegant" but  your idea to reuse of the remote the way you suggest is not "elegant".  But it's simple!  I agree with @joan - the problem you seek to solve is not really RPi-specific. More like EE.

Comment: that is a convoluted way to control the remote door opener ... this is an example of an `X-Y problem` ... instead, connect the relay in parallel with the switch ... closing the relay would be same as pressing the switch .... if you do not want to hack the remote, then use a hobby servo to push the button

Comment: does your garage door opener have a wall mounted control panel? ... it may be simpler to connect the RPi to that

Comment: @jsotola thanks, a relay in parallel with the switch seems like a simpler solution, I will try that one

Answer (score 1):

Using a relay should be your best bet. Also, if the device states that it requires 12V, it doesn't matter how small it is, you would need 12V. It's probably using an extremely low current: `W = V*I`. You might have better luck asking the [EE Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).